# SQLite before insert trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I'm trying to insert duplicates data to table `B` when `PKA` violated using a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` as the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE A( Col INTEGER, Coll TEXT(25), CONSTRAINT PKA PRIMARY KEY(Col, Coll) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_A ON A(Col, Coll);

CREATE TABLE B( Col INTEGER, Coll TEXT(25));
CREATE INDEX IX_B ON B(Col, Coll);

CREATE TRIGGER Trig
BEFORE INSERT
ON A
WHEN (Col = New.Col AND Coll = New.Coll)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO B(Col, Coll) VALUES(New.Col, New.Coll);
END;
```

But, it seems like the column `Col` is not accessible there, so it throws:

> no such column: Col

Even when I change the conditions to

```
New.Col IN(SELECT Col FROM A)
AND
New.Coll IN(SELECT Coll FROM A)
```

I get another error message:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: A.Col, A.Coll

While it shouldn't because of `ON CONFLICT IGNORE`.

- Why did I get those error messages? (What's the cause).
- How can I use the trigger to insert duplicates into another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_A ON A(Col, Coll);
```

because you have already defined `(Col, Coll)` as the `PRIMARY KEY` and furthermore, with this index, although you have `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` defined for a duplicate row, you will receive an error if you try to insert a duplicate row, because `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` is not defined for the index.
So drop it:

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS IX_A;
```

Now, change the code of the trigger to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig
BEFORE INSERT
ON A
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE Col = New.Col AND Coll = New.Coll)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO B(Col, Coll) VALUES(New.Col, New.Coll);
END;
```

`EXISTS` checks the table `A` if it already contains a row with column values the same as the ones to be inserted and if it does then the new row is inserted in table `B`.

You could also write the trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig
BEFORE INSERT
ON A
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO B(Col, Coll)
      SELECT Col, Coll FROM A
      WHERE (Col, Coll) = (New.Col, New.Coll);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right for the `unique index` which I didn't notice it. But could you explain a bit more why the pre-conditions `WHEN (Col = New.Col AND Coll = New.Coll)` doesn't works while `EXISTS()` works?

Comment: @Ilyes inside an insert/update trigger you can use the keyword NEW to refer to the column values of the new row. So NEW.Col and NEW.Coll are correctly defined. **But** `Col` and `Coll` are not defined anywhere. They need to be part of a SELECT...FROM... statement to be recognized as columns of a table. The fact that they are used inside a trigger defined for a particular table does not define them as columns of that table. On the other hand in a statement like: `SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE Col = New.Col AND Coll = New.Coll` they are correctly defined as the columns of `A`.